# OWASP ESAPI - JavaEncryptor can't be found / not in classpath - but ESAPI is working in other functions

Tags: maven, dependencies, java-ee-6, owasp, esapi

I already had [problems with the esapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543218/owasp-esapi-simpletest-in-a-maven-java-ee-project), but at the end it worked...

I included the OWASP ESAPI in my `pom.xml` like this

```
<!-- ESAPI Version 2.0.1 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

If i run this function:

```
String clean = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize("someString");
```

the ESAPI encoder works perfect...

But if I try to use the HASH function,

```
ESAPI.encryptor().hash(password, salt);
```

I got this result

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaEncryptor from [Module "deployment.demoapp_demo.war:main" from Service Module Loader] Encryptor class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaEncryptor) must be in class path.
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
```

but as you can see, the ESAPI is i my dependencys but JavaEncryptor can't be found....

```
joergi@nerdbook:~/dev/demoapp/trunk/demoapp_demo$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'dependency'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Java EE 6 webapp project
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] de.demoapp:demoapp_demo:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0-SP4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided (version managed from 1.0.0.Beta1)
[INFO] |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:jar:1.1.1.Final:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.0.0-beta-5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:1.1.0-alpha-2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.0.0-beta-5:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.0.0-beta-5:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.0.0.CR4:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api:jar:1.1.0-alpha-2:test
[INFO] +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- logkit:logkit:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- avalon-framework:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- xom:xom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-8:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.beanshell:bsh-core:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 14 23:17:07 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/342M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The search-results are not really helpful...

Anyone know this problem? (or can help anyway?)
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaEncryptor
```

to

```
org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto.JavaEncryptor
```

Comment: ah okay... cool thank you... i see, i can set in ESAPI.properties the location of the file...

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake, but codepitbull nailed the answer.

The problem is generally caused by using an earlier version of the ESAPI.properties file. At some point (during one of the later 2.0 release candidates IIRC), I reorganized some of the ESAPI crypto classes and created the org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto package and moved the JavaEncryptor class to it.  In a way, that's a good thing, because it makes using the ESAPI 2.0.x crypto to fail in a generally obvious way if one tries to use a ESAPI.properties file from ESAPI 1.4.x. If the class names were still the same between ESAPI 2.0.x and 1.4.x, attempts at encryption / decryption would still fail, but it would fail in a much more subtle manner.