# jBOSS+ ESAPI java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeLogger cannot be cast to org.owasp.esapi.Logger

Tags: java, maven, logging, jboss, log4j

I'm newbie Java developer and while trying to develop some website using JBOSS and ESAPI for security I'm getting exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeLogger cannot be cast to org.owasp.esapi.Logger
```

when I try to use ESAPI package from OWASP.

My Maven project consists of 2 modules: oak-parent and oak-web.

Maven dependency tree is as follows:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ oak-web ---
[INFO] org.me.oak:oak-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:provided
[INFO] +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss:jboss-vfs:jar:3.0.1.GA:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.0.0.CR1:provided
[INFO] +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- logkit:logkit:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- avalon-framework:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- xom:xom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.beanshell:bsh-core:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:0.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:jar:0.94:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
```

I've already created jboss-deployment-structure.xml to try to exclude log4j (file was created in oak-parent/META-INF:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
 <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
      <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
  <sub-deployment name="oak-web.war">
   <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
      <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
  </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

but still it didn't help with anything.

Do anyone of you know solution to this problem? JBoss classloader is a bit changed when comparing to jboss 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT (13.10.2014):**
I recommend using version 2.1.0 which fixed this issue with log4j classloader.

---

Finally I've managed to resolve this. Combined several methods available on the internet.

1. I've created `oak-ear` package
2. In oak ear I've added `src/main/application/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
       <deployment>
           <dependencies>
               <module name="org.mickula.mylog" />
           </dependencies>
           <exclusions>
               <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
           </exclusions>
       </deployment>
       <sub-deployment name="oak-web.war">
           <dependencies>
               <module name="org.mickula.mylog" />
           </dependencies>
           <exclusions>
               <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
           </exclusions>
       </sub-deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```
3. Next in `jboss` directory I've copied `org/apache/log4j/main/log4j.jar` to `org/mickula/mylog/main/` and created there `module.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.mickula.mylog">
       <resources>
           <resource-root path="log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
       </resources>
       <dependencies>
           <module name="javax.api"/>
       </dependencies>
   </module>
   ```

   This change allowed me to create own `log4j.properties` file.
   So did I in the `jboss/standalone/configuration/`.
4. Finally I've pointed JBoss to the new `log4j.properties` file via the starting script:
   in `jboss/bin/standalone.conf` at the end of the file I've added:

   `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=file://URL_TO_THE_JBOSS/jboss711/standalone/configuration/log4j.properties"`

Now running JBoss with ESAPI succeded. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Put log4j.properties file under resources folder with line:

```
log4j.loggerFactory=org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLoggerFactory
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but will it work with the JBoss log4j?

Comment: Worked for me at least, had exactly same exception

Comment: Hmm, bounced some problems later, but fixed those same way as below mentioned, here is some official info: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this exclusion:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I just found that on [this site](http://www.siteduzero.com/forum/sujet/jboss-enlever-un-module-du-deploiement). The suggestion is not verified there whether it works, but you can give it a try.

**Edit:**

Another way to exclude `log4j` is to make it at maven having:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

for the maven dependency of `esapi`. Could that make the desired effect? (I saw that you have it at dependency tree, and I looked for it 'cause I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543218/owasp-esapi-simpletest-in-a-maven-java-ee-project)).

Comment: thank you for the answer but I've already tried this exclusion

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned the version of your JBoss Application server but I guess its 7.X
Both interfaces org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogger and org.jboss.logmanager.log4j. BridgeLogger extends org.apache.log4j.Logger.

This is actually a variation on jboss issue with log4j which the common solution is excluding log4j as mico  suggested.

From the dependency tree I can see that you do not get log4j from esapi 2.0.1 dependency which depended on log4j (adding your pom would be useful). So it looks like your pom is fine.

My guess that  you still getting log4j from somewhere in your classpath.
 
Try using a variant of following (exclude on every level).

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
              <deployment>
                  <exclusions>
                  <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
                  </exclusions>
              </deployment>
              <sub-deployment name="MyWeb.war">
                    <exclusions>
                    <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
                    </exclusions>
              </sub-deployment>
              <sub-deployment name="MyBeans.jar">
                <exclusions>
                  <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
                </exclusions>
              </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

See also the following answer
[Using application's Log4J configuration under JBoss 7.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182257/using-applications-log4j-configuration-under-jboss-7-1-1).